# how to remove the extra space after last number

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, output

In my program, I am printing an extra space after the last number. How can I remove that?

```
def fibonacci(n):
a = 0
b = 1
if n == 1:
    print(a, end=' ')
else:    
    print(a, end=' ')
    print(b, end=' ')
    for i in range(2, n):
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        print(c, end=' ')

fibonacci(int(input()))
```

**Input:**  5
 **Output:**  0 1 1 2 3 
I'm printing an extra space after the last number.

Comment: Once you've printed something out, you can't really "unprint" it without using something like ANSII escape codes. It would be much cleaner if you returned a list of numbers from the function, then just called `" ".join(…)` on them.

Comment: The initial `a` value of `0` should not get printed - it's not considered a Fibonacci number. Alternately, you could start with `a` equal to `1`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want to print this sequence of numbers: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 ...
so, If I want to print 1 number from this sequence the output will be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the process of generating the numbers, from the process of printing them. (This is something you should do *anyway*, but it also happens in this case to make it easier to solve the problem.) For example, we can use a generator to `yield` multiple values. Notice that we don't need to handle any special cases, and we can also [use the pack-unpack idiom for multiple assignments](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/):

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    for i in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

Now we can display these values separated by spaces by using the `sep`arator for `print` rather than the `end`, and passing each of the values as a separate argument. To do that, we need explicit unpacking with `*`. It looks like:

```
print(*fibonacci(10), sep=' ')
```

And we get the desired result, with no trailing space:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55
```

Comment: your solution is working, just you should change the value of a = 1 to 0.

Comment: Again, 0 is *not a Fibonacci number*.

Answer (score 1):

A @Carcigenicate suggested you can use a list,

In the following code  have just replaced the `print` statements with `list.append()`

```
def fibonacci(n):
    l1=[]
    a = 0
    b = 1
    if n == 1:
        print(a, end=' ')
        l1.append(str(a))

    else:    
        l1.append(str(a))
        l1.append(str(b))
        for i in range(2, n):
            c = a + b
            a = b
            b = c
            l1.append(str(c))
    tr=" ".join(l1)
    print(tr,end='')
    print('h',end='')

fibonacci(int(input()))
```

output:

```
8
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13h
```

as you can see in the output there is no extra space after last number `13` and i have printed `h` after `13`.

hope this helps  you!